# how to link a url to neo4j node

Tags: neo4j, cql

I have some nodes and properties in neo4j.Below is my sample neo4j graph.

[image: sample graph created manually]

When we click on the **TheAct** node it will open a browser tab and display TheAct related properties or we have to show that TheAct related properties in a iframe.In the same way we have to achieve same feature for all nodes.
Is it possible with neo4j or can i goto another technology.
Thanks

Comment: your sample picture is not working, so we have no idea what are you actually asking

Comment: The answer is: yes

Answer (score 0):

Consulting documentation, it can be seen that we can set related properties on any node using simple Cypher Query:

```
MATCH (n { name: 'Andres' })
SET n.surname = 'Taylor'
RETURN n
```

Reference: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/set/

Answer (score 0):

URLs in properties make them clickable + browsable !